# mod_rewrite is not working with my urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am trying to make SEO friendly URLs of using apache mod_rewrite.

My normal URLs is something like this -

```
index.php?p=about
index.php?p=contact
index.php?p=this
```

My expecting SEO friendly URLs should be something similar to this -

```
localhost/php_advance/ch02/about
localhost/php_advance/ch02/contact
localhost/php_advance/ch02/this
```

I tried it with creating a `.htaccess` file and doing some changes to my apache `httpd.conf` file.

This is my .htaccess file

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on

# Set the base to this directory:
RewriteBase /php_advance/ch02/

# Redirect certain paths to index.php:
RewriteRule ^(about|contact|this|that|search)/?$ index.php?p=$1

</ifModule>
```

And also, At the end of the `httpd.conf` file, I added some code like this -

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/php_advance/ch02">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

`NOTE:` I am using WAMP server and Windows 07

But this coding is not working for me. Hope someone will help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: @anubhava, no I can't get 404. when I type `http://localhost/php_advance/ch02/about` on browser address bar I can get this `Not Found

The requested URL /php_advance/ch02/about was not found on this server.`

Comment: try this rule to test: `RewriteRule ^(about|contact|this|that|search)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,R]`

Comment: @anubhava I checked, but still not working.

Comment: It appears .htaccess isn't enabled. Put some garbage text on top of it and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error

Comment: In which page, do I need to add garbage text? .htaccess or ???

Comment: It should be on top of your `/php_advance/ch02/.htaccess` file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41752/discussion-between-tnk-and-anubhava)

Comment: Are you checking this with a Fully resolving domain ? Note that rewrite rules won't work with temp URLs as it won't read your .htaccess.

Comment: Are you using rewrite module as mod_php or rewrite module as a apache module, If this is apache module, See the following shows output  httpd -M | grep rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure mod_rewrite is turned on. In your httpd.conf file, you should have something similar to:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then make sure your htaccess file is in your `/ch02/` directory.

Comment: Jon Lin, do I need to insert this line of code `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` to my httpd.conf file? and yes my .htaccess file is in my `/ch02/` directory.

Comment: I checked my httpd.conf file and found mod_rewrite is turned on. This is that line from the file - `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /php_advance/ch02/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /php_advance/ch02/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Then I got this message - `Not Found

The requested URL /php_advance/ch02/about/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Normal url is something like this - `http://localhost/php_advance/ch02/index.php?p=about`

Comment: please look at http://www.larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1732-enabling-url-rewriting-not-working/#entry10674

Comment: @Win8_learner, I went through the thread which you have given, but I couldn't get a solution from it.